# trying to skip states with abreviations

Tags: python, nfa

I'm trying to use abreviations in this nfa to go from one state to another.

NFA is defined as

```
nfa = NFA(
start = 0,
finals = [6],
abrs = {1:5, 3:5},
edges=[
(0,'h', 1),
(1,'a', 2),
(2,'z', 3),
(3,'a', 4),
(4,'r', 5),
(5,'d', 6)
])
```

I've created this inner method when processing the string.

```
 char = ":"
 elif char is tape[index]:
        print " abreviation found!!"
        #goto to state

        gotoState = set([e[2] for e in nfa.abrs
                        if e[0] in nfa.edges and
                        tape[index+1] == e[1]
                        ])
        index += 1
```

When trying with test print => `print nrec("h:d", nfa, 1)` It returns false
The thing is that it's not creating the states. When the `:`-sign appears I want to create states that goes from example `("h:z")` that should gives all these states => `('h'->'a'->'z'->'a'->'r'->'d')`, how can I make modify this method to perform this task?
This is the defined method that process the string after creating the `NFA` structure.

```
def nrec(tape, nfa, trace=0):
"""Recognize in linear time similarly to transform NFA to DFA """
char = ":"
index = 0
states = [nfa.start]
while True:
    if trace > 0: print " Tape:", tape[index:], "   States:", states
    if index == len(tape): # End of input reached
        successtates = [s for s in states
                          if s in nfa.finals]
        # If this is nonempty return True, otherwise False.
        return len(successtates)> 0
    elif len(states) == 0:
        # Not reached end of string, but no states.
        return False
    elif char is tape[index]:
        print " abreviation found!!"
        #skip to state

        gotoState = set([e[2] for e in nfa.abrs
                        if e[0] in nfa.edges and
                        tape[index+1] == e[1]
                        ])
        index += 1
    # the add on method to take in abreviations by sign: :
    else:
        # Calculate the new states.
        states = set([e[2] for e in nfa.edges
                           if e[0] in states and
                              tape[index] == e[1] 
                      ])
        # Move one step in the string
        index += 1
```

How can I make the abreviation work properly and it returns true?

Comment: Hello. I don't recognize ``NFA(start = 0,finals = [6],abrs = {1:5, 3:5},edges=[......])`` as a Python structure. It is not a tuple, nor a dictionary.....

Comment: looks like missing not enough information